# Mysql Foreach Loop Syntax

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'posts' that has all info about my posts.
I want to insert a new row into a different table for all posts that are of type 'public'.
I want to run a query that would look something like this:

```
$ids = (SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE post_type = 'public')    
foreach($id in $ids){
    INSERT INTO new_posts (post_id, post_data) VALUES ($id, 'hello');
}
```

I know I can insert multiple rows in one sql statement, but I need the post_id to change for each one and there are too many for me to change it manually.

What is the correct mysql syntax for this that I can run in my database manager? (Adminer)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need a loop. You can do it in one query

```
INSERT INTO new_posts (post_id, post_data)
SELECT post_id, 'hello'
FROM posts 
WHERE post_type = 'public'
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!